# How to create new directory with current date in shell script?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I want to create a new directory with the current date. I wasn't able to create the directory. Please suggest a solution for this

```sh
export currentDate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y)
cd /mnt/volume-blr1-01/Jenkins/workspace/WebHook_Log_Backup/
sudo mkdir /mnt/volume-blr1-01/Jenkins/workspace/WebHook_Log_Backup/$currentDate
```

I have referred to the links below, but am not able to create a directory

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-directories-in-linux-with-the-mkdir-command/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/using-root-to-mkdir-in-another-users-home-directory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/716599/how-to-create-a-new-folder-from-a-terminal-with-administrative-permissions

Comment: Do you have any error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want create Jenkins Job or Pipeline you must use jenkins cli (example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBTzB9Kdx58) . When you create job add your variable with date to name and your job will be have timestamp